# groupBy did not do what I expected, what am I looking for?

Tags: haskell, grouping

```
isPermutation :: (Ord a) => [a] -> [a] -> Bool
isPermutation x y = sort x == sort y

isPermutation "123" "312" -> True
isPermutation "123" "111" -> False

groupBy isPermutation ["123","3","321"] -> ["123","3","321"] <- What I get

groupBy isPermutation ["123","3","321"] -> [["123","321"],"3"] <- What I would want
```

Is there a function that groups together items in a list that share the same properties?

Comment: I think you have to use `isPermutation "123" "321" -> True` in this mockup to get the right result

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`groupBy` only groups *consecutive* elements that share the same property e.g.

```
> groupBy (==) [1,2,1,1,2]
[[1],[2],[1,1],[2]]
```

To group all elements you need to sort the list first.

```
> groupBy isPermutation . sortBy (comparing sort) $ ["123","3","321"]
[["123","321"],["3"]]
```

(`comparing` is imported from `Data.Ord`)

Comment: Ah, simple solution as allways in Haskell. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

What you want is a multiway partition. Make use of [`Data.Map.insertWith`](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/latest/html/libraries/containers/Data-Map-Lazy.html#v%3ainsertWith):

```hs
Prelude Data.List Data.Map> Data.List.map (reverse.snd) $ toList $ 
   foldl (\mp s-> insertWith (++) (sort s) [s] mp) empty ["123", "3", "321"]
[["123","321"],["3"]]
```

This way each element is sorted only once.

Conversely, use the [*decorate-sort-undecorate*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwartzian_transform) idiom with the sorting solution.